# Fluent nhibernate table-per-hierarchy mapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a simple scenario where I have an entity Action (this is a workflow style application) that has a DueDate calculated property.

Now id like to introduce a SlidingAction, whose only difference (at this stage) is to override the DueDate calculation, as such has none of its own mapping.

Im having difficulty mapping this scenario since Fluent Nhibernate seems to be forcing me to map 'something' on the subclass.

Could someone shed some light?

Cheers,
Byron

```
public class ActionMap : ClassMap<Action>
{
    public ActionMap()
    {
        WithTable("Actions");
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.Description);
        Map(x => x.TimeLine);
        Map(x => x.Template);
        Map(x => x.StageOrder);
        Map(x => x.CorrespondenceType).CustomTypeIs(typeof (ActionCorrespondenceTypeEnumType));
        References(x => x.Matter).FetchType.Join();
        HasMany(x => x.FileNotes).Cascade.SaveUpdate();

        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Type")
            .SubClass<SlidingAction>(/*its forcing me to map something here*/);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put an empty lambda in, `c => {}`.

```
.SubClass<SlidingAction>(c => {});
```

Comment: brilliant, exactly what i was looking for :)